# What is the web server that suits my need?

Tags: webserver

I have a website which has around 500 visits per day, 10000 per month and it is powered by Joomla.

It is a website where user can create new entries and can also look up entries which are saved in the database. So, it communicates a lot with the database.

The website is very slow now and we plan to move it to a better server. I really need your help to know what the server specs to look at and how much would be sufficient.

Comment: Have you tried using other optimisation methods (CDN, minifying CSS & JS, mod_deflate compression and using MySQL COMPRESS() method - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress)? If not go with CloudFlare as CDN (if you want a free one) otherwise Amazon Cloud Front is a good one, and the compressfunction is not a bad idea for big data within tables ie. images from DB, or other binary data and as well for large texts (1000-1200+ chars)

Comment: Which web server do you currently use?